# How to use wget with `&` from ruby

Tags: ruby, wget

I'm trying to get a web page data like `http://example.com/foo.php?arg1=1&arg2=2`.

I can get the page by using `wget` without problem, but when I call `wget` from ruby script like:

```
`wget http://example.com/foo.php?arg1=1&arg2=2`
```

then wget only connect to `http://example.com/foo.php?arg1=1`. In short `wget` ignores second argument.

I also tried with `system` method, but it ends up same error. How can I use `&` with wget from ruby?

Comment: There are *so* many better ways to do that. open-uri or mechanize come to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround the url with quote to prevent shell interpreter `&`:

```
`wget 'http://example.com/foo.php?arg1=1&arg2=2'`
#     ^                                        ^
```

or escape the `&`:

```
`wget http://example.com/foo.php?arg1=1\\&arg2=2`
#                                      ^^^
```

**UPDATE** or you can use [`Shellwords::shellescape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) as Зелёный suggested:

```
"foo&bar".shellescape
# => "foo\\&bar"

require 'shellwords'
`wget #{Shellwords.shellescape('http://example.com/foo.php?arg1=1&arg2=2')}`
```

---

Or, use [`IO::popen`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-popen) (or [`Open3::*`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html)) which does not require escape:

```
IO.popen(['wget', 'http://example.com/foo.php?arg1=1&arg2=2']).read
```

Comment: also can use [`Shellwords#shellescape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape).

Comment: The quotes did the trick for me. So silly and yet so time consuming. Thanks!